# Как активировать в Wordpress у плагина polylang Custom post types and Taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

Не могу активировать Custom post types and Taxonomies в polylang.

Изначально стоит серым цветом. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Потом прочитал по [ссылке](https://polylang.pro/doc/multilingual-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies/), что нужно сделать поля публичными.

Поставил в `register_post_type` `'public' => true`.

Но все осталось прежним и просто невозможно добавить.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего вы не правильно создали пост тип или таксономию. Регистрация пост типа у вас на init?

Comment: Точно что я сделал сам не понял. Прыгал по сайтам. Добавил в functions.php action отсюда - https://github.com/WebDevStudios/custom-post-type-ui/issues/503. Удалил плагин полностью, установил. И все заработало. Что произошло еще не понял. Также добавил фильтры https://polylang.pro/doc/multilingual-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies/.  Наобум получилось. Буду сидеть до утра разбираться чтобы понять что произошло.

Comment: при чем удалить полностью и установить сыграло решающую роль

Comment: Все очень просто, не правильно сделали пост тип или таксономию) Полиленг проверяет наличие хотя бы 1 елемента и тогда становится активным этот пункт